# Fix “Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate X bytes)” with composer install

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

Fix “Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate X bytes)” with composer update

I am trying to install composer in window 10 to install zf2 by command prompt and setup.exe but getting same issue as mentioned memory issues.

Comment: Set `memory_limit=-1` in your _php.ini_ file.

Comment: I am still getting issue while installing composer:The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code 255]:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 303783 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: before coming this error, its asking for enter proxy url then I click on next then that issues comes in window.

Answer (score 0):

Specify memory limit using `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` environment variable before running composer:

for update:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

or for installing package:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install package/name
```

Answer (score 0):

In your git bash console try to type this instead of your regular "composer update" command :

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" update
```

Explanation :
memory_limit=-1 means you assign unlimited memory only for this composer update to run properly.

I personally prefer this method instead of tweaking your php.ini file...

Comment: added explanation